# Acknowledgement.acknowledge() throwing exception in spring-kafka @KafkaListener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When I set enable.auto.commit to false and try to manually commit offset using annotation based spring-kafka @KafkaListener, I get a **org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message**

I have a very simple code as follows:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "someid", topics = "${demo.topic}", containerFactory = "someContainerFactory")
public void listenFooGroup(String message, Acknowledgement ack) {
    System.out.println("Received Messasge in group 'foo': " + message);

    // TODO: Do something with the message
}
```

And when I send a message from the producer, I get the following exception:

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message.

Endpoint handler details:

Method [public void com.****.*****.*******.KafkaMessageListener.listenFooGroup(java.lang.String,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)]

> Bean [com.****.*****.*******.KafkaMessageListener@5856dbe4]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment] for GenericMessage [payload=test, headers={kafka_offset=57, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=demotopic}],
>   failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=test, headers={kafka_offset=57, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=demotopic}]

Please help. TIA.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to the set the container factory's `containerProperties` ackMode to `MANUAL` or `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` to get an `Acknowledgment` object.

With other ack modes, the container is responsible for committing the offset.

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE)
```

Or set the `....ackMode` property if using Spring Boot

Comment: 2.0 will [throw a less obscure exception](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/356) - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: It does not throw an exception now. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help.

Comment: The next release will throw [a more meaningful exception](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/356). `new IllegalStateException("No Acknowledgment availailable as an argument, the listener container must have a MANUAL Ackmode to populate the Acknowledgment.",`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Can somebody please tell me where to set the abovementioned ackMode property for Spring Boot.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on very old answers. `spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode` - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties

Comment: @abb factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue in spring boot 2.4.3 by applying the following to application.properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual
```

Set ack-mode to manual or manual_immediate, based on your use case.